# GitHub Actions not creating Rust binaries

Tags: rust, github-actions, rust-cargo

I am using GitHub Actions to cross-compile my Rust program. The action completes successfully, and files are created in the target directory, but there is no binary. This is my workflow file:

```yaml
name: Compile and save program

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
    paths-ignore: ["samples/**", "**.md"]
  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs:    
  build:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        target: 
          - aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
          - i686-pc-windows-gnu
          - i686-unknown-linux-gnu
          - x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
          - x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
          
    name: Build executable
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Rust
        uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          toolchain: stable
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          rustup target add ${{ matrix.target }}
      - name: Build
        uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          use-cross: true
          command: build
          args: --target ${{ matrix.target }} --release --all-features --target-dir=/tmp
      - name: Debug missing files
        run: |
          echo "target dir:"
          ls -a /tmp/release
          echo "deps:"
          ls -a /tmp/release/deps
      - name: Archive production artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: ${{ matrix.target }}
          path: |
            /tmp/release
```

And this is the layout of the created directory when targeting Windows x86_64 (the only difference when targeting other platforms is the names of the directories within `.fingerprint` and `build`):

```
.
├── .cargo-lock
├── .fingerprint/
│   ├── libc-d2565b572b77baea/
│   ├── winapi-619d3257e8f28792/
│   └── winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-7e7040207fbb5417/
├── build/
│   ├── libc-d2565b572b77baea/
│   ├── winapi-619d3257e8f28792/
│   └── winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-7e7040207fbb5417/
├── deps/
│   └── <empty>
├── examples/
│   └── <empty>
└── incremental/
    └── <empty>
```

As you can see, there is no binary, and this is reflected in the uploaded artifact.

What is causing this?

**EDIT 1**

The program builds fine on my local device. My `.cargo/config.toml` is below.

```ini
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc"
```

And this is my `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "brainfuck"
version = "0.4.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
console = "0.15.2"
either = "1.8.0"
```

**EDIT 2**

While messing around in a test repo, I discovered that this issue only arises when specifying the target. If I don’t specify a target and just use the default system target, I get a binary as expected.

Comment: In your build command, you have overridden the target dir to be `tmp`: with the flag `--target-dir=/tmp`

Comment: @Anonyme2000 I know, that's where the `ls` command is looking, and it's where the artifact is being uploaded from

Comment: Are you sure `cargo` succeeded? Did it output anything? What does your project look like? Do you need to specify a `--bin` target?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The last output from `cargo` is `Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 1m 47s`. My project consists of two rust files. `main.rs` has the main logic for the program, and `text.rs` is a library containing static variables that I didn't want to clutter my `main.rs` with. I will add more details to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn’t read the cargo docs properly. The [build cache docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/build-cache.html) mention that the results of a build with a specified target are stored in `target/<triple>/debug/`, and that is indeed where they were.